# How to delete "Duplicated" views

Tags: objective-c, view, slide

I have my main view that has 3 `UIButton` that sends to 3 other views, I also have a slide menu (like the one used by facebook app) that has another 3 buttons that sends to the same 3 views of the buttons on the main view. I go to the views with a segue method, the problem is that using the buttons on the slide menu I create duplicates of the view (e.g if i press twice on the second button i'll create 2 identical views) is there a way to delete duplicated views that uses segue method?

Comment: Please elaborate yours question, when do u want to delete those duplicate buttons? when u go back to view1 and then again go to view2?
or when u set 0 as the number of buttons to view1 to view 2. or the previously set buttons are not gettin deleted?

Comment: I want to delete the duplicated views, for example:
I'm in the first view and i press the button (inside the View) that sends me to the 2nd View, then when i'm in the second view I open the slide menu and press  the button that sends me to the 2nd View again, now after pressing the button I have 2 duplicate of the 2nd View.

Comment: is the slider inside the first view or second?

Comment: the slider is inside (almost) every View

Answer (score 0):

if u know the names of the view u can always call
[myView removeFromSuperview]; method to remove your view that is u are creating dynamically so yeah u can remove it like this,

hope it helps